# ReactJS - {this.props.children} is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen many post related this argument but i'm not able to understand why `{this.props.children}` is undefined in my application (i'm really new to ReactJS)

Starting with `App.js` that is my main component i have this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Dashboard from './layouts/Dashboard';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div id="container">
                <Dashboard />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So, `Dashboard.js` have to code to render a top bar and a left-side bar, the "dynamic" content will go on the center (and this is where i have placed `{this.props.children}`)

```
Dashboard.js

render() {
    return(
        <div className="content" id="wrapper">
            <!-- Navbar and sidebar code -->
            <-- this is the dynamic content -->
            <div id="page-wrapper" className="page-wrapper" ref="pageWrapper">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The router right now is very simple:

```
<Route component={App}>
    <Route path='/' component={Home} />
</Route>
```

I have omitted the code related to Home.js, but this is a simple `div` that print in statyc way `"Hello World"`

Dashboard component is renderd but no "Hello World" is placed in the part where i have {this.props.children}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass children to Dashboard:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div id="container">
                <Dashboard>{this.props.children}</Dashboard>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't access the children of your component through this.props.children. this.props.children designates the children being passed onto you by the owner:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    // This doesn't refer to the `span`s! It refers to the children between
    // last line's `<App></App>`, which are undefined.
    console.log(this.props.children);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div><span/><span/></div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App></App>, mountNode);
```

To access your own subcomponents (the spans), place refs on them https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Answer (score 1):

`Dashboard` has no children.

Change `<Dashboard />` to `<Dashboard>{this.props.children}</Dashboard>` in App.js so  your Dashboard component can have access to the component you [pass through the `Route`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#route).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if children exists in your Dashboard.js

```
render() {
  return <div>{this.props.children !== undefined && this.props.children}</div>
}
```