# React generic containers communication with deep children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this case which I'm trying to approach in React, but I don't know if it's even possible given the React paradigm...

I have a `Slideshow` component and a `Image` component which are supposed to be part of a UI library. The `Image` component manages some kind of special cases (like lazy-loading) and we want to integrate seamlessly with this `Slideshow`, but it needs to be controlled by this `Slideshow` (which is the one controlling the logic of which Slides are being shown at each moment).

The problem is, `Slideshow` accepts arbitrary components to be used as Slides, so there's an abstraction layer between `Slideshow` and `Image`.

That's my case. A generic question would be something like *how to communicate an element with a children which can be in any level of deep*.

Something like

```
<Slideshow>
  <Slide>
    <Image />
  </Slide>
</Slideshow>
```

but we don't know how the structure of the `Slide` component would be.
It might be something simple like

```
<div>
  <h3>{title}</h3>
  <div>
    <div>{description}</div>
    <Image />
  </div>
</div>
```

or more complex like not using the `Image` directly, but inside another subcomponents...

So the real question is...

Is it possible for the `Slideshow` (parent component) to detect the instances of the `Image` component (a specific type of component) between its children and the children of the children, and then call some method or re-set any property, without the intermediate elements having to implement anything?

If all the slides (intermediate components) need to implement some special logic to allow this (like passing a special property or a method to their children), it kind of loses the meaning of what we want to do (and this was completely possible in the non-react implementation because we had more control of the DOM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React's context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). That's basically the only "regular" solution. In your case however, I'd probably use some instance that only deals with lazy loading and pass it here and there :

```
<SlideShow loader={myLazyLoader}>
  <div>
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    <div>
      <div>{description}</div>
      <Image loader={myLazyLoader}/>
    </div>
  </div>
</SlideShow>
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! We followed that approach and got a working solution based on contexts :)

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Is it possible for the Slideshow (parent component) to detect the instances of the Image component (a specific type of component) between its children and the children of the children, and then call some method or re-set any property, without the intermediate elements having to implement anything?

**A:** basically, yes, you can, if you manage your Slideshow component render, you can check for the `children` prop on the component, with that you will be able to get all the components inside the Slideshow but it isn't as easy as that, you will have to start checking the structure inside to see what you need to implement.

here you have a good article about [React children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren).

Comment: And, at the same time you have this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743321/reactjs-this-props-children-is-undefined so you cannot access the children of your children????

Comment: No but your children can access their children.